# How to insert specific column of Excel into Database

Tags: java, database, spring, hibernate

I have an Excel sheet with 200+ column names and each column has a header name. I have to fetch all the header names first from the Excel sheet using Java and pass them into Oracle DB. The DB returns only a few header names, say 150, which I need to insert into a table.

My problem is that I am unable to fetch the specific header names (150 out of 200) from the Excel sheet and their values to insert into db.

I tried using a CSV file but it cannot fetch specific column values. Please suggest any solution that I need to follow here.

Answer (score 0):

1) Have you tried to read the csv file like regular text file, then extract the first line, the header row, into a String? Then separate the string by "comma" and you should have an array of string with column headers.

2) Make sure you don't have any "unusual" characters such as "dash", "comma", "quote" in your column header description.

Gook Luck

Comment: Yes am able to that ie, get the header name as you said but how can I filter the specific header values from CVS? Say H1, H2, H3 are my headers but I need to insert only H1, H3 header with their values